How do I fix; openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400?
from openai import OpenAI

prompt = input("What would you like an image of? ")

def generate_image(prompt):
    response = (client.images.generate(
        model="dall-e-3",
        prompt=prompt,
        n=1,
        quality="standard",
        size="1024x1024"
    ))
    image_url = response["data"][0]["url"]
    return image_url

I have tried redownloading OpenAI, changed different aspects of the image and check to make sure my API_Key was correct and active

Are you sure all the arguments are correctly named and formatted? It's not an unauthorized response so the request is getting through but it doesn't like what you've sent in some way. Assuming the error code is accurate on their end.

This cannot be the full code, because the generate_image function is defined but it is never called.

Please check if you have enough credits for that request.

Usually 400 comes with an additional message, because Bad Request is a pretty generic HTTP status code. In my case, trying to reproduce the example led to the following error:
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'code': 'billing_hard_limit_reached', 'message': 'Billing hard limit has been reached', 'param': None, 'type': 'invalid_request_error'}}

It seems that when trying to insert bad data, the wrong data error message has priority over this one. Could be, maybe you have a free account?
Take a look over your remaining credits: https://platform.openai.com/settings/organization/billing/overview.
We won't know for sure, until you look at the associated response body of your request.
